Como retirar esses comentarios do código no vs code?
Alguém sabe como retirar estes comentários que ficam aparecendo no código?


Veja que VSCode e Visual Studio são IDEs diferentes, eu vou aceitar a edição sugerida mas vou remover algumas tags.

Em Settings, digite editor.inlayHints.enabled na barra de pesquisa.
O seu deve estar como "on", basta colocar como "off", para desabilitar completamente, ou escolher uma das outras opções intermediárias.

Veja que o código do usuário é java. No VSCode algumas extensões Java sobrescrevem as configurações do editor para hints inline. Talvez algumas pessoas tenham que entrar no arquivo settings.json e modificar/adicionar a linha java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled para o valor "none".
